# How does Maven manage duplicate artifactIds when they belong to a different group?

Tags: java, maven

I'm building some different web projects with **Maven** and thinking about how to name their artifacts. For the REST API layer, it's convenient to share some classes, so I want to create *exchange-api.jar* files which will be shared among different projects.

Let's suppose I've got a web application which has it's own exchange-api module. The *groupId* would be `com.mycompany.app1` so the whole maven id for the artifact should be `com.mycompany.app1:exchange-api:1.0`. Now let's suppose I want to access other app's API from this application. I have to include the dependency `com.mycompany.app2:exchange-api:1.0`. *artifactId*s are the same, but the *groupId* is different. However, both should end up as *exchange-api-1.0.jar* in the classpath.

How does Maven take care of this? Should I use a unique *artifactId* for each of them?

Comment: The first thing which is coming into my mind. If i read `-api` than i assume this is only an interface but nothing which contains real implementation in contradiction your post sounds like that. Apart from that having same names for artifacts in a lib folder for an war archive is simply not possible. You can change the [filename mapping in maven-war-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/file-name-mapping.html). Apart from that i have have code in command i would name it like `commons.jar`.

Comment: @khmarbaise, I name them `-api` because they're kind of interfaces and simple POJO's. Just because of that. However that's not the root of the problem. The real issue is if it's possible for Maven to include this two artifacts in the classpath, even though they've same `artifactId`, but the whole maven artifact id is different. I don't know if Maven looks for this at build time and renames the included jars to be able to place them in the `WEB-INF` directory... BTW, the namespaces for classes in the jar files will be different, so they don't collide in any way.

Comment: You didn't read my questions cause there is a hint about `filename mapping`.

Answer (score 1):

Maven manages this problem allowing you to customize the file name mapping, this can be done both for [WAR](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/file-name-mapping.html) and [EAR](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/customize-file-name-mapping.html) applications.   However I think that your naming convention is poor.  Suppose that your projects are publicly downloadable and people not using Maven download them manually and add them to their projects: do you think that a generic "exchange-api" would be clear enough?  I think no.  Good names are `app1-exchange-api` and `app2-exchange-api`.  Or simply `app1-api` and `app2-api`.  There are several examples of this rule: Spring, Hibernate and so on.

Comment: The link seems to address my problem, many thanks. I haven't stablished the names yet, it was just a matter of clarification ;-)

Comment: @khmarbaise, correct. I want to manage them into a WAR file and not an EAR one. Didn't notice the link was about the maven EAR plugin.

Comment: Names customization can be done in WAR too. I have just added a link for WAR applications to my answer above.